# Typescript: Property 'set' does not exist on type '{}'.ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

This is my `store.tsx`:

```
let store = {};

const globalStore = {};

globalStore.set = (key: string, value: string) => {
    store = { ...store, [key]: value };
}

globalStore.get = (key) => {
    return store[key];
}

export default globalStore;
```

And I use it:

```
import globalStore from './library/store';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    globalStore.set('cookie', pageProps.cookies);
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

But I get this error:

> Property 'set' does not exist on type '{}'.ts

My code work fine, but I don't want get any error.

Actually, I want to store my data to variable and use it from another component.

Comment: Don’t assign the properties of globalstore. Declare them inline

Comment: @DanielA.White How? can you help me more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you basically declared the type of the variable as `{}`, and you  can't *easily* change that after the fact.

So you need to declare the functions inside to object so typescript can infer the correct type of `GlobalStore` (with the methods):

```
const store: Record<string, string> = {};

const GlobalStore = {
    set: (key: string, value: string) => {
        store[key] = value;
    },
    get: (key: string): string => {
        return store[key];
    }
}

export default GlobalStore;
```

The correct type of `GlobalStore` would be (in opposition to the `{}` you currently have):

```
interface GloabStore {
    set(key: string, value: string): void;
    get(key: string): string;
}
```

And btw, what you are implementing is basically a (Hash)`Map`, so I think you could just do:

```
const GlobalStore = new Map<string, string>();

export default GlobalStore;
```

Comment: @RezMohsnei Yes! Please read the post again, I didn't (for some reason) realize that you don't really need instances. I updated the answer now so the first approach also makes sense :)